# XSLT : Data flow top to bottom and then left to right in a page

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an xml file with some data like :

```
<A>
  <B>
    <X>(some information)</X>
    <Y>(some information)</Y>
    <Z>(some information)</Z>
  </B>
  <B>
    <X>(some information)</X>
    <Y>(some information)</Y>
    <Z>(some information)</Z>
  </B>
  <B>
    <X>(some information)</X>
    <Y>(some information)</Y>
    <Z>(some information)</Z>
  </B>
  <B>
    <X>(some information)</X>
    <Y>(some information)</Y>
    <Z>(some information)</Z>
  </B>
 .....(multiple B tags)
</A>
```

I need to show the contents of all B's in pdf with each page containing 2x2 data sorted based on values in X tag. The catch is  - it has to be filled top to bottom in a page, then left to right.By default a row gets filled first left to right. Can the column be done first in a page and then the rows.

In case I miss something, please let me know.
Code - what I had for filling row first(works perfectly) :

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed">
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)" />
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)" />
            <fo:table-body>
                <xsl:for-each select="B">
                    <xsl:sort select="X" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid" height="3.4in"
                        font-size="7pt">
                        <xsl:attribute name="starts-row">
                            <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">true</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="ends-row">
                            <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">true</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:call-template name="TEST" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

Comment: I think I have a vague idea of what you want. It sounds like a transposition of a matrix. However, would it be possible that you replace the `(some information)` snippets by something distinguishable and then give us a draft of what the positioning of the snippets should be in your target layout?

Comment: I managed to do it , by explicitly making 2 rows within a column. Then making a new column again and filling 2 rows. However, there were minor issue with page end etc. But for now it worked.
Thank You!!